# How do i open ajax request in separate frame?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Okay, I have this code:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function requestPage(page) {

    var request = false;

    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            alert("Unable to complete your request.");
            return false;
            }
        }
    }

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == 4) {
            if(request.status == 200) {    
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        }
    }

    request.open("GET", "include.php?page=" + page, true);
    request.send(null);
}

//-->
</script>
```

then obviously making it happen like so:

```
<a onclick="javascript:requestPage('red_the_clown')"><li>Red</li></a>
<div id="content"><?php include('index2.php'); ?></div>
```

I have been pulling my hair out trying to work out how to target a separate frame instead of the current frame. I.e.: the #content div will be in _main, but it is being called from a frame.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

Comment: Is 'content' the frame you are trying to access?
So you are saying 
that document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = request.responseText;
is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access the document from inside a frame?

top refers to the top most frame.  parent refers to one level up.

Your Javascript above might just need one change:

```
top.document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

However, you'll need both frames to be from the same domain, or else you'll be restricted by browser security.

Comment: well if he does have x-domain issues he's completely SOL anyway

Answer (score 0):

so you have an iframe with id "_main"?

how about

```
window.frames["_main"].document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

Comment: no sorry by main i meant parent (or top, im not sure of the difference)

Comment: let me clarify, the link thats requesting is in a frame, the content div that needs to be filled is not

window.frames["_parent"].document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = request.responseText; doesnt work